# How do I save and display my data in SharedPreferences as a list?

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, sharedpreferences

I am using SharedPreferences to save and load data saved as a string. I want to be able to save the data as a list, how do I do this and add to the list, instead of replacing the data?

This is how I save the data:

```
public void saveButton(View v) throws JSONException {
    String data = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.randomJokeSetup)).getText().toString();
    String data2 = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.randomJoke)).getText().toString();
    SharedPreferences datafile = getSharedPreferences("my_data_file", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = datafile.edit();
    editor.putString("setup", data);
    editor.putString("punchline", data2);
    editor.commit();

    Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.save), "Joke saved!", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

This is how I load the data:

```
public void loadButton(View v){
    SharedPreferences datafile = getSharedPreferences("my_data_file", MODE_PRIVATE);
    String setup = datafile.getString("setup","");
    String punchline = datafile.getString("punchline","");
    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.loadJokeSetup)).setText(setup);
    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.loadJoke)).setText(punchline);
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Save ArrayList in shared preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17895888/save-arraylist-in-shared-preferences)

Comment: @VaibhavGoyal Hi, not really, I'm a beginner so i dont really understand how to use that with my code

Answer (score 0):

You can turn your list to [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) with [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) or whatever you like and save it on SharedPreferences and when you wanna get data from it, get elements you need from that JSON string.

for more information look at [this tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-save-arraylist-to-sharedpreferences-on-android)